# Canvas element can't be drawn on after jquery display transition

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating a drawing app using canvas. It works fine if the div containing the canvas element is shown. However, I want to initially have the containing div hidden and then "launch" the drawing app using a jquery transition to fade in the drawing interface. So the containing div initially has its css 'display' property set to 'none' and then I show it. However, when I do this, the canvas element will no longer receive any drawing input. I've tried setting the display:none dynamically after the canvas element is rendered by my script to make sure there's no interference there, but no dice. Any suggestions?

Here is the html structure for the drawing interface:

```
<!--DRAWING INTERFACE-->
    <style>
       #draw-container {
         display:none;
         width:1920px;
         height:1080px;
         position:absolute;
         top:0px;
         left:0px;
       }
     </style>
<div id="draw-container">
    <h1>Send a Drawing</h1>
    <div id="draw" class="panel">
    </div>
    <div id="draw-buttons">
        <a id="sendButton" href="#" class="round">></a>
        <a id="clearButton" href="#" class="round">+</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this function gets called, which creates the canvas element as a child of the "draw" div:

```
//creating canvasses
function drawCanvas(id,xOffset){
    //draw
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    canvas.id = id;
    $('#draw').append(canvas);
}
```

And when a user clicks on a button to reveal the drawing module:

```
document.getElementById('drawLaunch').addEventListener("click", function(){
    $('#draw-container').show();
});
```

And finally, here's the drawing function:

```
function _drawCircle(mouseX, mouseY) {
//get position
var x = mouseX - offsetLeft,
    y = mouseY - offsetTop;
//move mouse to the previous point
if (lastX == null) {
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}
context.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
//draw line
context.lineTo(x, y);
context.stroke();
//set new last point
lastX = x;
lastY = y;
```

}

Now, if I keep everything the same but just remove the 'display:none;" from the stylesheet so that the canvas is shown when the page is loaded, everything works fine. But if it's hidden and then shown, you can't draw on it.

Answer (score 6):

```
 #draw-container {
     visibility:hidden;
     width:1920px;
     height:1080px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
   }
```

Can you use visibility:hidden instead of display:none? That way the element stays present on the page just not visible to the naked eye?

When you want it to be visible again just write

```
  visibility:visible;
```

or in your code

```
document.getElementById('drawLaunch').addEventListener("click", function(){
    $('#draw-container').css('visibility','visibile');
});
```

Comment: Added a little more to my answer

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just a note for anyone else who needs this -- it should be "visible", not "visibile".

Comment: Sorry for the typo - please check me off if the answer was correct. Thanks!  I updated the code so its visible